# Visa to remote-work in Spain for a few weeks

Tags: visa, spain

I am a British citizen, living in the UK, working for a UK company.  We have an office in Spain, and I'd like to work in the Spanish office where the rest of my team is based for 6 weeks taking my spouse and kids with me.

Which visa would I need for this?

I know I'll not be earning `Spanish` income, and will be there for less than 189 days for tax purposes, but is this a valid use of a tourist visa?

Comment: As a British citizen, you do not need a visa for to go to Spain for less than 90 days. Whether you need a visa or not, such a stay is governed by Schnegen short stay rules. They are not limited to tourism and cover any purpose, with an important caveat. While “business” stays are allowed without any prior permission, “work” might require an additional explicit authorisation (which is not a visa and is in fact required to apply for a visa, if your citizenship made one necessary). That would be something your company has to apply for.

Comment: I don't know what the exact procedure is in Spain but that's the question you need to answer.

Comment: http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Pages/Visas.aspx

Comment: Thanks @AaronF - From that site is looks like I should be fine since I'm not going there for "Gainful Employment"